# Android billing API version 3 and consuming purchases

Tags: android, in-app-billing

IAB is almost 100% working in my Android app. I can make it through the purchase flow (Google Play dialog, enter password etc) and get a "purchase successful" dialog message. However the immediate consumption of the purchase isn't working. What's interesting is the inventory check plus immediate consumption on app start-up works.

In my `PurchaseFinishedListener` do I need to do an inventory check before consuming the purchase? Or can I immediately call `consumeAsync`?

My intuition was I can pass the successful purchase (returned to `PurchaseFinishedListener`) to `consumeAsync`. Why would I need to do another inventory check? However the fact that the consumption check works on app start-up (when I consume the product from the results of an inventory check) makes me question things.